# django forloop _set.all in html response

Tags: python, django, http, response

I am making a website for my school but for some reason(http responce)

```
{% for article in menu.article_set.all %}
    <li>{{ article.text }}ff</li>
{% endfor %}
```

doesn't give any thing back

my models are

```
class Menu(models.Model):
    menu = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s: %s' % (self.menu_order, self.menu)

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    menu = models.ForeignKey(Menu)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s: %s' % (self.title_order, self.title)
```

my view

```
def detail(request, menu_id):
    menu = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=menu_id)
    return render(request, 'rijnijssel/detail.html', {'menu': menu})
```

and my urls

```
    url(r'^specifics/(?P<menu_id>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

i just started django and i don't understand why it doesn't work.
just for testing i got a menu with the name 'home' and a article linkt to it with the name 'test' and a random text in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view, you've queried an Article, although you've called it `menu`. You probably meant to use Menu there.